# ggplot warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: ymin, ymax

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am getting an error I can't figure out.  This may well be something dumb, like a misspelling or missing parens, but I can't see it.

My plot command:

```
ggplot(df, aes(flim, flam, group=1)) +
  geom_point(aes(size=foo)) + geom_line() +
  geom_smooth(stat='identity', aes(ymin=flam - flam_c95,
              ymax=flam + flam_c95))
```

I get:

```
Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: ymin, ymax
```

Without the geom_smooth, no warning.  flam and flam_c95 exist in df.  I have done this before plenty of times. What am I missing?

I am using R 3.2.4, ggplot 2.2.0 which warns it was built for R 3.2.5.

Comment: Maybe you mean to use `geom_ribbon`?  `geom_smooth` doesn't take `ymin` and `ymax`; the documentation lists which aesthetics a geom understands under the "Aesthetics" heading.

Comment: @aosmith - did that change recently I've been using ymin and ymax with geom_smooth and stat='identity' for years without trouble. I guess I'll use geom_ribbon.

Comment: I've never used `stat = "identity"` in `geom_smooth` so I can't tell you when it changed.  However, among other changes starting in ggplot2_2.0.0 layers got much more strict on arguments and some other long-standing hacks no longer work.  Read through the [news](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/NEWS.md) for specifics.

Comment: If you submit 'use geom_ribbon' as an answer, i'll accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `geom_ribbon` in place of `geom_smooth` with `stat = "identity"` to draw intervals around your line.

```
geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=flam - flam_c95, ymax=flam + flam_c95))
```